# Inserting an element after every 'X' React components

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a React component that renders a list of items into three columns using Bootstrap's `col col-md-4` styles. However, I need to [insert a clearfix div](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets) after every third element to ensure that the next 'row' of elements displays in the correct place.

My current render code looks like this:

```
render() {
  var resultsRender = $.map(this.state.searchResults, function (item) {
    return <Item Name={ item.Name } Attributes={ item.Attributes } />;
  }

  return (
    <div>{ resultsRender }</div>
  );
}
```

`Item` simply renders a div with the `col` classes, containing the passed-in content:

```
render() {
  return(
    <div className='col col-md-4'>
      ...content here...
    </div>
  );
}
```

My current workaround is to pass the index of the `Item` in as a prop, and then apply the clearfix class to the `Item` if the index is a multiple of 3, but this feels a bit hackish to me and I would prefer a separate `div` to allow me to only show the clearfix on the required viewport size (using Bootstrap's `visible-*` classes).

I'm sure there must be a more elegant way to solve this problem than the one I've come up with. Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could iterate your array and add a `<div/>` every 3 items:

```
render() {
  var items = $.map(this.state.searchResults, function (item) {
    return <Item Name={ item.Name } Attributes={ item.Attributes } />;
  }

  var resultsRender = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    resultsRender.push(items[i]);
    if (i % 3 === 2) {
      resultsRender.push(<div className="clearfix" />);
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>{ resultsRender }</div>
  );
}
```