# Displaying a different component within a list after the second item and then display the rest of the original list React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to insert another component within a list in React after the second item in the list. The original list comes from an API call and is returning an array of objects which I am then mapping over to display in a component. All of that works fine and I have been able to insert the other component following this example: [Inserting an element after every 'X' React components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36619418/inserting-an-element-after-every-x-react-components). My question is there a better way to do that with hooks or just in React period. Here is an example of my code:

```
/*THIS IS THE ARRAY OF OBJECTS FOR INITIAL LIST*/
const totalCars = [
    {
      name: 'Ford Mustang',
      color: 'red',
      year: '2017',
    },
    {
      name: 'Subaru Crosstrek',
      color: 'white',
      year: '2019',
    },
    {
      name: 'Toyota Prius',
      color: 'silver',
      year: '2016',
    },
    {
      name: 'Nissan Rouge',
      color: 'black',
      year: '2017',
    },
]
```

Here is the main app component:

```
const CarList = () => {
   const cars = totalCars.map((car, i) => (
     <CarContainer 
       name={car.name}
       color={car.color}
       year={car.year}
     />
   ))
}

let updatedCars = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
  updatedCars.push(cars[i]);
  if (i === 3) {
   updatedCars.push(<CarAd />);
}

return (
  <App>
   <div className="list-container">
     {updatedCars}
   </div>
  </App>
)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can do the loop inside of JSX instead of looping through your data twice to insert the ad.

```js
<div>
  {totalCars.map((car, i) => (
    <>
       <CarContainer key={remember to add a key} />
       {i === 3 && <CarAd key={remember to add a key} />
    </>
  ))}
</div>
```

Comment: That worked perfectly and was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the help.